# Is The Inverse Laplace Transform of $e^{st}\operatorname{Log}\left(\frac{s+1}{s}\right)$ doable using inversion formula?

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, laplace-transform, complex-integration, inverse-laplace

I'm trying to solve inverse laplace transform using inversion formula and given by this integral:
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma-i\infty}^{\gamma+i \infty} e^{st}\operatorname{Log}\left(\frac{s+1}{s}\right)\,\Bbb ds.$$

Here is my contour, since the branch points of $\operatorname{Log} \left(\frac{s+1}{s}\right)$ are $0$ and $-1$
[image]

First, i want to show integral on $L_u\cup L_d$ is $0$ by bounding the integral with ML and then take the limit when $R$ goes to $\infty$.

By letting $L_u,\, L_d: s= \xi\pm iR,0\leq \xi\leq \gamma$, where $\gamma$ is the real number that the vertical line of the given contour passed by.

Since the $L$ is $\lvert e^{t(\xi\pm iR)} \rvert$, then i have ML inequality as below:

$$\lvert F(s)e^{st} \rvert \leq M_R \lvert e^{t(\xi\pm iR)} \rvert = M_R e^{\xi t} \leq M_R e^{at}$$

Next, i need to find $M_R$ and take the limit.
$$\begin{align}
\left|F(s)\right| &= \left|\operatorname{Log}\left(\frac{s+1}{s}\right)\right|\\
&= \left|\operatorname{Log}\left(\frac{\xi\pm iR+1}{\xi\pm iR}\right)\right| = M_R
\end{align}$$

And by taking the limit of the last expression when $R$ goes to infinity yields $0$. Meaning the integrals along those lines are $0$.

So, from here, am i doing this right? I'm not sure my work is correct. Maybe there are some mistakes there. Help me please!

Edit:
Working with my $L_u$ with $ML$ inequality, i have $L=\gamma$. Assuming $-\pi<\operatorname{arg}{s}\leq \pi$ and parametrizing $s=-\xi+iR$, $\xi\in [-\gamma,0]$:

$\begin{align}
\left|\int_{L_u}\right| 
&\leq \left|e^{st} \log\left(1 + \frac 1s\right)\right|\\
&\leq \left|e^{-\xi t}\right| \left|e^{iRt}\right|\left|\ln\left|1+ \frac{1}{-\xi+iR}\right| + i\pi\right|\\
&\leq 1\cdot 1 \cdot \ln\left(1+\frac 1R\right) + \pi\\
&\approx \frac 1R + \pi
\end{align}$

Combining the $ML$ i have
$$\frac{\gamma}{R} +\gamma\pi$$
Which does NOT approach to $0$. Why? Please spot my mistake. I can't think about how to make it goes to $0$ since yesterday. Hope you kind to help me.

**New Edit**: Now my main question is not about ML. I managed to set the big and small arc goes to $0$. My main question now is "is it possible to evaluate this by using inversion formula (without differentiate both sides) and use log form instead?"

What i mean by differentiate both sides is:
$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}^{-1} &= \operatorname{Log}\left(\frac{s+1}{s}\right)\\
(\mathcal{L}^{-1})' &= \frac{1}{1+s} - \frac{1}{s}
\end{align}$$

I don't want this kind of solution. What i really want is evaluating $\operatorname{Log}\left(\frac{s+1}{s}\right)$ by inversion formula. That's it.
because I keep getting integrals on the contour lines above and below the branch cut cancel each other and make everything 0, which of course I don't want it.

Attempt:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\LARGE\left. a\right)}$

One idea, in this *particular case*, is to get rid of the $\ds{\ln}$-function by introducing an integral representation of it. Namely,
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\left.{1 \over 2\pi\ic}
\int_{\gamma\ -\ \ic\infty}^{\gamma\ +\ \ic\infty} \expo{st}\ln\pars{s + 1 \over s}
\,\dd s\,\right\vert_{\,\gamma\ >\ 0}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{\gamma\ -\ \ic\infty}^{\gamma\ +\ \ic\infty} \expo{st}\
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{1}{\dd x \over x + s}}
^{\ds{\ln\pars{s + 1 \over s}}}\
\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{\gamma\ -\ \ic\infty}^{\gamma\ +\ \ic\infty} 
{\expo{st} \over s + x}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{1}\bracks{t > 0}\expo{-xt}\,\dd x =
\bbx{\bracks{t > 0}\,{1 - \expo{-t} \over t}} \\ &
\end{align}

---

$\ds{\LARGE\left. b\right): {\large Contour Integration}}$'

Note that $\ds{{s + 1 \over s} < 0}$ whenever
$\ds{s \in \pars{-1,0}}$: It indicates that the $\mbox{$\ds{\ln}$-branch-cut}$ lies along $\ds{\bracks{-1,0}}$. Also,
$\ds{{s \pm \ic\epsilon + 1 \over s \pm \ic\epsilon}
\,\,\,\stackrel{{\rm as}\ \epsilon\ \to\ 0^{+}}{\sim}
\,\,\, \pars{1 + s \over s} \mp {\epsilon \over s^{2}}\,\ic}$ such that the $\ds{\ln}$-$\ds{arg}$ is $\pars{-\pi}$ when $\ds{s}$ is above the real axis and $\ds{\pi}$ when it's below the real axis.
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\left.{1 \over 2\pi\ic}
\int_{\gamma\ -\ \ic\infty}^{\gamma\ +\ \ic\infty} \expo{st}\ln\pars{s + 1 \over s}
\,\dd s\,\right\vert_{\,\gamma\ >\ 0}}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\int_{-\infty}^{-1}\ln\pars{s + 1 \over s}\expo{ts}
{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}\label{1}\tag{1}
\\[2mm] - &\
\int_{-1}^{0}\bracks{\ln\pars{-s - 1 \over s} - \ic\pi}\expo{ts}
{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[2mm] - &\
\int_{0}^{-1}\bracks{\ln\pars{-s - 1 \over s} + \ic\pi}\expo{ts}
{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[2mm] - &
\int_{-1}^{-\infty}\ln\pars{s + 1 \over s}\expo{ts}
{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}\label{2}\tag{2}
\end{align}
I included (\ref{1}) and (\ref{2}) "by completeness" but, indeed, it's not necessary because the $\ds{\ln}$-branch-cut lies along $\ds{\bracks{-1,0}}$
albeit it guarantees the vanishing out of the integration along the"big-arc".

Then,
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\left.{1 \over 2\pi\ic}
\int_{\gamma\ -\ \ic\infty}^{\gamma\ +\ \ic\infty} \expo{st}\ln\pars{s + 1 \over s}
\,\dd s\,\right\vert_{\,\gamma\ >\ 0}}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\int_{0}^{1}\bracks{\ln\pars{-s + 1 \over s} - \ic\pi}\expo{-ts}
{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[2mm] &\
\,\, + \int_{0}^{1}\bracks{\ln\pars{-s + 1 \over s} + \ic\pi}\expo{-ts}
{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{1}\expo{-ts}\,\dd s =
\bbx{1 - \expo{-t} \over t} \\ &
\end{align}

Comment: (+1) Thanks. But i'm afraid it still doesn't answer my question about using my contour to perform the ILT. Because the new integrand inside the integral w.r.t $s$ has different contour with mine. Maybe if you can explain why i can't use my contour i'll accept this answer, though i already upvote your answer. Still many thanks for the answer!

Comment: @user516076 I just included the contour integration.

Comment: Thank you for your wonderful answer!

Comment: @user516076 Thanks. Glad to see it's useful.

Comment: Hi, Felix. It's been a while since you posted your answer, hope I don't interrupt you. Anyway, the term $\ln$ on the  last paragraph about contour integration, can I replace the bracket with absolute value? Just in case when I'm evaluating and do u-subs I wouldn't get negative inside $\ln$?

Answer (score 2):

Let's pick a sufficiently large $\gamma$ such that $|s|>1$, so that we can plug in

$$
\log\left(1+\frac1s\right)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty{(-1)^{k+1}\over ks^k}
$$

and get

$$
\begin{aligned}
f(t)
&={1\over2\pi i}\int_{\gamma-i\infty}^{\gamma+i\infty}\sum_{k=1}^\infty{(-1)^{k+1}e^{st}\over s^k}\mathrm ds \\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty{(-1)^{k+1}\over k}{1\over2\pi i}\int_{\gamma-i\infty}^{\gamma+i\infty}{e^{st}\over s^k}\mathrm ds
\end{aligned}
$$

Provided that

$$
\mathcal L\{t^{k-1}\}(s)={(k-1)!\over s^k}
$$

we can deduce

$$
\begin{aligned}
f(t)
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty{(-t)^{k-1}\over k!} \\
&=-\frac1t\left[\sum_{k=0}^\infty{(-t)^k\over k!}-1\right] \\
&={1-e^{-t}\over t}
\end{aligned}
$$

where the final step follows from the fact that

$$
e^z=\sum_{n=0}^\infty{z^k\over n!}
$$

Comment: Ok. Nice and thanks . Actually i know the ILT already, But sorry, my question is why did I fail to perform complex inversion formula to logarithm directly? Without splitting the log term, is that "doable"?

Comment: @user516076 I am unsure about that since most of the texts I have found often differentiate to eliminate logarithms in the integrand (perhaps to avoid dealing with logarithmic branch point)

Comment: Ok. Still seeking my answer. Btw i still (+1) for your kindly giving another approach.